# Increase time in a counter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

So I've got a timestamp (string) displaying on the page in this format: `1h 49m 58s ago`

Every second, I'd like it to increase that timestamp +1 second. Then at the end of a minute, add to the minutes and reset the seconds, add to the hours, reset the minutes, etc....

So I'm guessing I need to split the string at the numbers find out what number needs to go up or be reset, do a .replace() and add it back into the DOM.

Here's what I've got but I'm at a bit of an impasse, ay suggestions?

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.timestamp-large').each(function(){
        theData = $(this).html().split()
        console.log(theData)
    });
},1000)
```

Comment: How is this timestamp generated? If at all possible, store it as an integer, perhaps in a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: I'd parse it done, create a datetime object and store that for future reference. Then re-output now-originalTime as a duration string.

Comment: This is *not* a timestamp, you have got a time string. Have you searched the web/stackoverflow for javascript counters/clocks/countdowns?

Comment: change the delay (1000) to a variable and you cant change it as you will , and use a set Timeout instead

Comment: @Charmander I get it from my server via an $.ajax call. Pulling that down every second would be totally killer for the server, so i'd like to modify it via JS.

Comment: @Bergi actually, it's a timestamp coming from a server that I'm outputting as a string.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: That was not what I meant. Store it once, as an integer (UNIX timestamp, e.g.) and subtract to obtain the difference from `new Date`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You don't have a timestamp, but a string representing a time difference